# ask for user input for selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm trying to automate my workflow using selenium in nodejs. When accessing  sellercentral.amazon.com it sends an OTP code to my phone. How can I ask for a prompt at nodejs so I can input the code?

I've tried using readline-sync, but the prompt is always displayed even before selenium starts.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    // .setFirefoxOptions(options)
    .build();

//Main body
driver.get('https://sellercentral.amazon.com');
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('sign-in-button')));
driver.findElement(By.id('sign-in-button')).click();

const fillForm = (idToLook, keys) => {
    this.idToLook = idToLook;
    if (keys) {
        driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id(idToLook)));
        driver.findElement(By.id(idToLook)).sendKeys(keys);
    }
    else {
        keys = readline.question(`what are the keys for ${this.idToLook}: `);
        driver.findElement(By.id(idToLook)).sendKeys(keys);
    }
}

fillForm('ap_email', amazon.id);
fillForm('ap_password', amazon.password);
driver.findElement(By.name('rememberMe')).click();
driver.findElement(By.id('a-autoid-0')).click();
driver.wait(until.elementIsNotVisible(By.id('auth-mfa-optcode')));

// fillForm('auth-mfa-otpcode');

driver.findElement(By.id('auth-mfa-remember-device')).click();


driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try something in similar fashion . Wrap initializeSite to launch the site as a Promise .

A base script like the below:

```
function main() {

    var initializeSite = initialize();

    initializeSite.then(function(result) {





        // Do your different actions to bring up the form that need OTP

       readline.question (“Add OTP”, (otp) =>{

       // Add rest of your codes here
      }

        console.log(“success”)

    }, function(err) {

        console.log(err);

    })

}
```